# Реально ли создать свой php-протектор?

Tags: php

Привет всем!
После прочтения статьи из хакера появилась идея создать свой php-протектор (по типу ionCube, zend и т.д.)
Вопрос к шарящим и опытным: реально ли и насколько это сложно?)
Ссылка на журнал - http://xakep.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/xa_06_2012_low.pdf
Статья начинается на 90 странице

Comment: То есть фраза "и мутим свой php-протектор" вам ни о чем не говорит?

Answer (score 1):

свой уникальный и нормальный будет сложно написать и в реали он нафиг не нужен :)

сори за слово.

---

за такие вещи отвечает и существует другое ПО